# call the unregister function of any addon by its file name, addon name, or file path

Tags: python, add-on, customization

I need to call the unregister function before disabling the addon.
I can get this information about the addon:

```
addon_collection = {}
for addon in addon_utils.modules():
    addon_name = addon_utils.module_bl_info(addon)
    addon_file_name = addon.__name__
    # my_name.update({addon_name['name'] : addon_file_name})
    addon_items = {addon_name['name'] : addon_file_name}
    addon_collection.update(addon_items)

print(addon_collection)
```

I get such a dict with keys.

```
{'Magic UV': 'magic_uv',
'TexTools': 'TexTools_1_5',
'3D Navigation': 'space_view3d_3d_navigation',
'Stored Views': 'space_view3d_stored_views',
'Cycles Render Engine': 'cycles'}
```

Also, I can get the path to the file:

```
for addon in addon_utils.modules(refresh=False):
    print(addon.__file__)
```

```
D:\blender\0\3.1\scripts\addons\node_presets.py
D:\blender\0\3.1\scripts\addons\node_wrangler.py
D:\blender\0\3.1\scripts\addons\space_view3d_align_tools.py
D:\blender\0\3.1\scripts\addons\object_boolean_tools.py
D:\blender\0\3.1\scripts\addons\object_carver\__init__.py
D:\blender\0\3.1\scripts\addons\object_fracture_cell\__init__.py
D:\blender\0\3.1\scripts\addons\drop_it\__init__.py
```

From these lists it turns out that I can refer to the addon

1. By file name
2. The name of the addon
3. The path to the addon file

**How to call unregister function?**
Without knowing the internal classes or other functions that have different names, but are somehow called when the unregister function is triggered.
Thank you in advance )

Answer (score 0):

```
import object_fracture_cell
if "unregister" in dir(object_fracture_cell):
    object_fracture_cell.unregister()
```

If you prefer `try/except`

```
import object_fracture_cell
try:
    object_fracture_cell.unregister()
except AttributeError:
    print("No unregister function in object_fracture_cell addon")
except RuntimeError:
    print("object_fracture_cell has already been unregistered")
```

From my understanding if the addon is a single file, blender will seek a `unregister` function inside it and nothing else, and if it is a multifile addon, it will seek `__init__.py` then seek the `unregister` function and nothing else.

So you can assume that if an addon can be unregistered, importing it then calling `my_addon.unregister()` will call all the `unregister` logic.

However I don't think it is mandatory for an addon to have an `unregister` function so you should add an `if` or `try/except` block.

for instance :

```
import node_presets

print(dir(node_presets))

import object_fracture_cell

print(dir(object_fracture_cell))
```

```
['AddonPreferences', 'Menu', 'NODE_MT_template_add', 'NODE_OT_template_add', 'NodeTemplatePrefs', 'Operator', 'StringProperty', '__addon_enabled__', '__addon_persistent__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__time__', 'add_node_button', 'bl_info', 'bpy', 'classes', 'node_center', 'node_search_path', 'node_template_add', 'node_template_cache', 'os', 'register', 'unregister']
['BoolProperty', 'EnumProperty', 'FloatProperty', 'FloatVectorProperty', 'FractureCell', 'IntProperty', 'Operator', 'StringProperty', '__addon_enabled__', '__addon_persistent__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__time__', 'bl_info', 'bpy', 'main', 'main_object', 'menu_func', 'register', 'unregister']
```